Pyspark UDF function returns multiple variables not working
I have a python function that I want to use it as udf function in pyspark. This python function has this format
def function(parameter):
    list1 = [{"aa":"bb", "cc":"dd"}, {...},{...},...]
    list2 = [{"aa":"bb", "cc":"dd"}, {...},{...},...]
    
    ...

    return list1, list2

Each list contains dictionaries and each dictionary can have a set of keys. The format of the dictionaries are defined through a StructField.
How can I defined the return_data of this udf in order to get each list and further use it?

looks you're looking for pandas_udf which can return an pd.DataFrame and as an StructType column in further spark code.

And what would be the most efficient and optimal way to implement this? One pandas_df for each list of dict or each list of dict to be on a column in pandas_df? Later on, this data will be written in a database.

what is your expected return from this udf? Also, are list1, list2 calculated from Columns from the spark dataframe? it would be more helpful if you can add some sample data and show the desired result, so there is no guess work from viewers' end.  most likely you can handle this in one pandas_udf but might need some post processing to complete the task.

an udf can only return 1 output afaik. you could be creative and return a list of lists, in your case, which can be further processed in spark to create separate columns
